# strongswan not establishing connection

Tags: amazon-ec2, vpn, strongswan

I'm creating a VPN using StrongSwan. It's my first time using this tool. I followed a tutorial to set up. I've hit a blocker whereby the peer connection times out. The status is `0 up, 1 connecting`.

I have tried on different servers, the same issue happens.

ipsec.conf

```
conn conec-example
  authby=secret
  left=%defaultroute
  leftid=<public_IP_1>
  leftsubnet=<private_ip_1>/20
  right=<public_IP_2>
  rightsubnet=<private_ip_2>/20
  ike=aes256-sha2_256-modp1024!
  esp=aes256-sha2_256!
  keyingtries=0
  ikelifetime=1h
  lifetime=8h
  dpddelay=30
  dpdtimeout=120
  dpdaction=restart
  auto=start
```

ipsec.secrets

```
public_IP_1 public_IP_2 : PSK "randomprivatesharedkey"
```

Here is part of the logs:

```
Aug 18 17:29:01 ip-x charon: 10[IKE] retransmit 2 of request with message ID 0
Aug 18 17:29:01 ip-x charon: 10[NET] sending packet: from x.x[500] to x.x.x.x[500] (334 bytes)
Aug 18 17:30:19 ip-x charon: 13[IKE] retransmit 5 of request with message ID 0
Aug 18 17:30:19 ip-xcharon: 13[NET] sending packet: from x.x[500] tox.x.x.129[500] (334 bytes)
Aug 18 17:31:35  charon: 16[IKE] giving up after 5 retransmits
Aug 18 17:31:35 charon: 16[IKE] peer not responding, trying again (2/0)
```

I expected a successful connection after setting up this, though no success. How can I resolve this? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use `tcpdump` on both ends and to check if the packets from the other side arrive. You should see **UDP packets to port 500 or 4500**. If you're on EC2 make sure the inbound **Security Group** permits these from the other side.

Hope that helps :)